# How to grab specific key in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a list called `students`. Inside of `students` there are 10 dictionary entries each containing 3 key, value pairs. I am only wanting to grab the last key. All 10 entries look like this:

```
{
    'first_name': 'Toni',
    'last_name': 'Stokes',
    'assignments': [('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 85), ('assignment3', 94), ('assignment4', 100)]
}
```

after obtaining the grades for the assignments I need to sum them. How do I only grab that key as well as the grade that it contains?

Comment: You mean to grab `assignments` (if keys are uniform for all sub-dictionaries0?

Comment: @SeyiDaniel yes that's correct

Comment: You want the last key in each of the 10 dictionary (i.e. "assignments") or the last key of the key-value pairs (tuples) for each assignment ? Or the last key of the last assignment ? ... ?

Comment: @ApplePie I need to specifically get: 'assignments': [('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 85), ('assignment3', 94), ('assignment4', 100)] and grab the value of those and average them but for all 10 entries at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a dictionary of dictionaries that look like this:

```
students = {
'dict1': {
    'first_name': 'Toni',
    'last_name': 'Stokes',
    'assignments': [('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 89), ('assignment3', 94), 
('assignment4', 100)]
},
'dict2': {
    'first_name': 'Alex',
    'last_name': 'Stones',
    'assignments': [('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 88), ('assignment3', 94), 
('assignment4', 100)]
},
'dict3': {
    'first_name': 'Tati',
    'last_name': 'Stikes',
    'assignments': [('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 95), ('assignment3', 94), 
('assignment4', 100)]
}
    #... up to dict10
}
```

with a `for loop` you can access all the keys and the keys of the sub-dictionaries this way:

```
for i in students:
    print(students[i]['assignments'])
```

> Result

```
[('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 89), ('assignment3', 94), ('assignment4', 100)]
[('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 88), ('assignment3', 94), ('assignment4', 100)]
[('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 95), ('assignment3', 94), ('assignment4', 100)]
```

> **FOR EDIT 1**

```
for i in students:
    print(f'{students[i]["first_name"]} {students[i]["last_name"]}\n')
    for i,j in students[i]['assignments']:
        print(f'{i}: {j}')
```

> Result:

```
Toni Stokes
assignment1: 97
assignment2: 89
assignment3: 94
assignment4: 100

Alex Stones
assignment1: 97
assignment2: 88
assignment3: 94
assignment4: 100

Tati Stikes
assignment1: 97
assignment2: 95
assignment3: 94
assignment4: 100
```

Comment: Thank you! now is there any way that I can narrow that down to only grab the grade?

Comment: `total = sum(grade for _, grade in student[i]['assignments'])` then `'average = total / len(student[i]['assignments'])`

Comment: @RootTwo I'm still confused about what exactly goes into the first portion of sum

Comment: @SeyiDaniel, probably shouldn't use `i` in both for loops.

Comment: @GarrettStarkey, if you look at Seyi's edit, the line `for  i,j in students[i]['assignments']` iterates over the assignments list, and uses tuple-unpacking to assign the first part of the tuple ('assignment1' etc) to `i` and the second element of a tuple (97, 89, etc) to 'j'.  I used `_` for the first element, because I don't really care about it (that's a Python convention), and `grade` for the second part.  The part in the `()` is a generator expression that yields all the grades in the assignment list.

Comment: @RootTwo though each loop is a different response, what's the problem with using `i` in both loops?

Comment: @SeyiDaniel, if there code was more complicated, it would be easy to get confused as to which `i` is which.  It is a future bug waiting to happen.  Better to use different loop variables in nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

So , you need to sum all the grades of students .
This can be achieved By first running a for loop as the elements(dict)
are in a list
And then you can easily get tuple by using assignment as key and after
that you can get grade

```
for dict_elements in students:
    total_grades = 0
    for elements in dict_elements["assignments"]:
        total_grades += total_grades[-1] # IN THIS CASE LAST INDEX IS GRADE
                     or
        total_grades += total_grades[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

### students = [{'first_name':'','last_name':'','assignments':[]},{},{}...]
result = [student.get(list(student.keys())[-1]) for student in students]

[[('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 85),('assignment2', 85)],[('assignment1', 97), ('assignment2', 85),('assignment2', 85)],[],[]...]